# Was Frosty the snowman born on December 25 Christmas Day?

Tags: character, frosty-the-snowman

In the original movie the snow fell on the day before Christmas but it is not specified how many days  it took for the children to build him. Is it assumed he was built within a single day on Christmas day?

Comment: It seem entirely clear to me that he was made on December 24th,

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but why are you so interested in Frosty the Snowman's birthday?

Comment: @Adam H  Is there an original Frosty the Snowman movie?  According to Wikipedia it was originally a song written in 1950.  Wikipedia has an article about it and a list of television and movie adaptations.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frosty_the_Snowman

Comment: @M.A.Golding OP's questions seem to specifically be about [the 1969 Rankin/Bass special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frosty_the_Snowman_(TV_special)).

Answer (score 1):

On December 24, between 3:00pm and 4:00pm frosty came to life for the first time. By dusk, frosty came to life for the second time, and began counting and speaking.

My source, the film:

In the opening narration, the narrator, clearly states that what follows happens on the day before Christmas.

The children get out of school at 3pm on the dot, and they go straight to building a snowman, shortly after they place the hat on Frosty and he comes to life and says "happy birthday". Moments later, the hat is removed. A short time later the hat returns and is placed on Frosty's  head again.

All of this happens before the sun sets, and appears to take place before dusk, so I think it is safe to say definitively that Frosty's birthday was December 24th.

What remains unclear, is the year of his birth. I don't think there was any mention in the film to a specific year.

Frosty The Snowman entered popular culture as early as the 1950s - source: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frosty_the_Snowman

An extensive breakdown of the films, songs and publications depicting Frosty's adventures can be found here http://toonopedia.com/frosty.htm

Comment: That's not a source, that's a google search. If that links to an actual source, can you possibly revise the link to actually link there?

Comment: I've updated the link to a video of the film

Comment: Are you saying that's just the film that's asked about? That's even less of a source, it's simply an implicit source of the entire question and all its answers. If you just reasoned based on the actual film, then just say that, there's no need to link to it, let alone mention it explicitly as a source.

Comment: Well, I guess that depends on how you want to look at it. I mean we are talking about a fictional character, depicted in multiple films, so I think it is fair to consider  this film as a source, of the recounting of the characters life and journey... No? At any rate, I explicitly referenced the film, as I don't know of anything considered more canon than that specific film.

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify that the film is my source, I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: If there's multiple films and this isn't the one the question is about or if it's unclear which one the question is about, then *naming* the film is even more useful than a link.

Comment: I've added some addition links to the many songs, films and publications centered around Frosty, but to be clear I would consider the initial song, and the above linked film as canon, and is what my answer is based off of.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Paulie_D on this one, if not sooner.  They built Frosty right after the school closed for Christmas vacation.  So, before the 25th.